# Not able to renew my Magento 2 certifications

Tags: magento2

Adobe ask to watch any 3 videos and then go to certmetrics and click on renew your certifications and assessment link should be there. But in my case I have watched 3 videos. but assessment link in not showing in my certmetrics renew your certifications link. Not sure how to renew this. Anyone facing the same issue?

https://express.adobe.com/page/Vm1xF5EEBySxZ/

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the related certmetrics from https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/certification/program/technical-certifications/ac/ac-renew.html?lang=en#
[image: Check the image]

More importantly, you need to log in using the certification email in the certmetrics before taking the exam.

Comment: Thanks Sohel, I have given that assessment 3 days ago but still my certifications not renewed. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: That's worried. For me it took 24H. You need to log in using your cert credential that's the only important thing you should be careful about.  Others are as usual.

Comment: Hi Sohel. My one certification is renewed. but others 2 didn't renewed. For that I checked this url https://express.adobe.com/page/MhfRSoA3rA0r6/
Here is no assessment url but only course url. Can you please check

Comment: Not sure which one was renewed. You need to pass 3 assessments for Expert, master, and 3 assessments for professional

Comment: I have 2 Expert Certifications. But only one renewed. Not sure how second will get renewed. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Does your cert retire? Like JS expert.

Comment: No, this is cert. Name -   Adobe Certified Expert - Adobe Commerce Cloud Developer (Adobe Commerce)

Comment: This cert also retires. So, you can't renew or retake.